# Helping out with popup menu

Tags: java, android, button, popup, fragment

I have an Android music app. It is a pad app using SoundPool to play the sounds.
What I would like to implement is a page where the user could choose his own chords.
I've already implemented a popup menu, it works, but I have no idea how to change the button once I click on the chosen chord in the popup menu.

I am providing a screenshot so you would see what I mean.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Has anybody got an idea how to make something like this?
Basically the button would be grey, then you choose a chord, that changes the color and text of the button and the onclick event too to play a chord.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this, https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/BubbleLayout

Comment: post what have done so far.

Comment: @ganesh-pokale sorry but no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

First, the grid of buttons would actually be a RecyclerView with custom views and a GridLayoutManager.

Second, I would have a model class associated with each item in the RecyclerView. This model will contain the sound it is supposed to play and other stuff that you may want.

Third, I would have a custom adapter attached to the RecyclerView. Each item would have an associated model object with it. When I click on an object, I would first check if it has some sound attached to it (by checking the associated model object). If it is, I would simply play the sound. If not, I will show the popup menu. On selection of the popup menu, I would update the associated model with the selected data and then update the view of the button.

**EDIT (Doing the same with a GridView)**

The logic behind what you want to achieve will be mostly similar to the above with changes to how you manage the items. Here are the steps required

First, you will have to create a GridView consisting of as many buttons as you look. Assign each button a unique id so it is accessible.

Second, create a model class (same as in the case of RecyclerView).

Third, attach click listeners to each of your buttons in the GridView. On click, you will check the model object associated with that button. If it has some sound attached to it, you will play the sound. Else, you will show the popup menu and on selection of an item, assign it to the model object.

Comment: Let me know if you want me to further elaborate any of the above mentioned steps.

Comment: That sounds interesting. I will have to read more about RecyclerView as I have never used that. Btw, I am using Fragments. Does that affect this method?

Comment: @derpaherpa not at all. You can use a RecyclerView in your fragment.

Comment: Could I use GridView instead of RecyclerView?

Comment: Technically you can. However, that would require you to add click listeners on each of the grid items separately. I will update my answer to include how to do it with a GridView.

Comment: Noob question but what is a model class?

Comment: @derpaherpa just a POJO class. A class which holds fields and methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that you can implement it.

1.Implementing through a view

implementing this functionality through a view, this has one advantage over the  contextual menu that you can design your own view and implement it like the app of Pinterest and all

2.implementing through a contextual menu

A Contextual menu is inbuild function that lets you implement the menu type. This is the inbuild view and you can implement writing few lines of code